# Mocking/Stubbing CosmosDB connection to perform unit testing node js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking for any method that I can use to mock connections to Azure in order to perform Unit Testing. Are there any good reliable mocking npm modules available.

Answer (score 1):

I was going down this path to mock out the cosmo client and db container.

```
jest.mock('@azure/cosmos', () => {
return {
    CosmosClient: jest.fn(() => ({
        database: jest.fn(() => ({
            container: jest.fn(() => ({
                items: {
                    query: jest.fn(() => ({
                        fetchAll: jest.fn(() => ({
                            resources: [{ cat: 'dog' }],
                        })),
                    })),
                },
            })),
        })),
    })),
}
```

for mocking the following

```
const client: CosmosClient = new CosmosClient('...')
const database: Database = client.database('...')
const container: Container = database.container('...')

const querySpec = {
    query: `SELECT * from ...`,
}

const response: Model[] = await (
        await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll()
    ).resources
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jest is a general purpose JavaScript testing framework](https://jestjs.io/). It provides several different ways to do mocking both at the module/import level as well as for individual functions. There are other options out there like Sinon for mocking but I find Jest has everything you need out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Most of my unit testing is done using the sinon, mocha. I'll check how I can fit this into for what I need to achieve.

Comment: If you're already using Sinon then you should be able to mock your interactions with CosmosDB

Comment: I am facing issues mocking this piece of code. If you have any idea about to do that then it would be helpful 
`let DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;
let docDbClient = new DocumentDBClient(config.COSMOS_DB.HOST, {
  masterKey: config.COSMOS_DB.AUTH_KEY
});`